# Trigger creating single record instead of multiple

Tags: apex, trigger

I am working on one trigger, I have TWO objects

1. Opportunity
   2)SOW__c

SOW__c is having lookup to Opportunity and with trigger I need to create sharing records, those who have access to opportunity need to have access to SOW__c also, I tried below apex class

```
public class SOWSharingRecordClass {
public static void SOWSharingToOpportunity(List<SOW__c> allSOW){
    set<Id> Opportunitiesset = new set<Id>();
    Map<Id,List<OpportunityShare>> oppshareMap1 = new Map<Id,List<OpportunityShare>>();
    List<SOW__Share> SOWSharesToInsert = new List<SOW__Share>();
    for(SOW__c sow: allSOW){
        if(sow.Opportunity__c != null){
            Opportunitiesset.add(sow.Opportunity__c);
        }
    }
    for(OpportunityShare opp: [select Id,OpportunityId,UserOrGroupId,OpportunityAccessLevel  from OpportunityShare where OpportunityId in: Opportunitiesset]){
        List<OpportunityShare> listshare = oppshareMap1.containskey(opp.OpportunityId)?oppshareMap1.get(opp.OpportunityId):new List<OpportunityShare>();
        listshare.add(opp);
        oppshareMap1.put(opp.OpportunityId,listShare);
    }
    for(SOW__c sow: allSOW){
        if(oppShareMap1.containsKey(sow.Opportunity__c)){
            for(OpportunityShare ops : oppShareMap1.get(sow.Opportunity__c)){
            SOW__Share sowshare = new SOW__Share();
            sowshare.ParentId = sow.Id;
                for (OpportunityShare m:oppShareMap1.get(sow.Opportunity__c)){
            sowshare.UserOrGroupId = m.UserOrGroupId;
                }
                for (OpportunityShare m:oppShareMap1.get(sow.Opportunity__c)){
            sowshare.AccessLevel = m.OpportunityAccessLevel;
                }
            sowshare.RowCause = Schema.SOW__Share.RowCause.Access_To_Opportunity_Users__c;
            SOWSharesToInsert.add(sowshare);
        }
        }
    }
    insert SOWSharesToInsert;
}
```

}

Above trigger is creating only 1 record in sow share even though there are multiple records in Opportunityshare.

Can anyone help me out in this issue please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into what you are doing in the following code:

```
Map<Id,OpportunityShare> oppShareMap = new Map<Id,OpportunityShare>();
for(OpportunityShare opp: oppShare){
   oppShareMap.put(opp.OpportunityId,opp);
}
```

You have created a map collection that will have opportunity ID as the key and a single OpportunityShare record as the value. When you use `put` method of map collection, the value corresponding to the key is updated/ overwritten. So, you'll end up with only one OpportunityShare record per opportunity.

Instead, your map collection should be `Map<Id, List<OpportunityShare>> oppShareMap = new Map<Id, List<OpportunityShare>>();`. And, your code should keep adding the additional OpportunityShare records to this list.

Comment: thanks a lot for helping me out, I have updated the code in question, am I doing code good now?

Comment: The 2 nested `for` loops seems pointless. You are fetching the list from map collection and updating the same entry inside the `for` loop (basically, overwriting the entry), This way you'll end up with multiple share records to insert but with the same `UserOrGroupId` & `AccessLevel` values per OpportunityShare record. Instead, get rid of these nested loops and use `ops` to get the field values.